# Mails sent from Roundcube on xampp not visible in Gmail,Yahoo or Hotmail Inboxes

Tags: php, smtp, imap, webmail, roundcube

I have downloaded and installed Roundcube 0.9.5 on my xampp server on Windows 8.It works well when receiving mails as the mails show up in inbox normally.

But when i send a mail from the logged in account in roundcube(say gmail or yahoo) , I am able to see that mail in 'Sent' folder of the Sender but not able to see the mail land up in the Receiver's Inbox not even in Spam folder.

Can anyone tell me what problem it could be? I have configured Roundcube to take up the **SMTP** and **IMAP** settings from the user login so as to support multiple smtp servers using [**this**](https://github.com/unstko/Roundcube-plugins/tree/master/multiple_smtp_server) plugin and my config folder's **main.inc.php** has these respective variables for that:

```
// IMAP
// ----------------------------------
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = array (
    'ssl://imap.gmail.com:993' => 'Google',
    'ssl://imap.mail.yahoo.com:993' => 'Yahoo',
    'ssl://imap-mail.outlook.com' => 'Outlook'
);

$rcmail_config['multiple_smtp_server'] = array (
    'Google' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587',
    'Yahoo' => 'ssl://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465',
    'Outlook' => 'starttls://smtp-mail.outlook.com:587'
);

// TCP port used for IMAP connections
$rcmail_config['default_port'] = 993;

// IMAP AUTH type (DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN or null to use
// best server supported one)
$rcmail_config['imap_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN';

// If you know your imap's folder delimiter, you can specify it here.
// Otherwise it will be determined automatically
$rcmail_config['imap_delimiter'] = null;

$rcmail_config['imap_ns_personal'] = null;
$rcmail_config['imap_ns_other']    = null;
$rcmail_config['imap_ns_shared']   = null;


$rcmail_config['imap_force_caps'] = false;

$rcmail_config['imap_force_lsub'] = false;


$rcmail_config['imap_force_ns'] = false;

// IMAP connection timeout, in seconds. Default: 0 (no limit)
$rcmail_config['imap_timeout'] = 0;

// Optional IMAP authentication identifier to be used as authorization proxy
$rcmail_config['imap_auth_cid'] = null;

// Optional IMAP authentication password to be used for imap_auth_cid
$rcmail_config['imap_auth_pw'] = null;

// Type of IMAP indexes cache. Supported values: 'db', 'apc' and 'memcache'.
$rcmail_config['imap_cache'] = null;

// Enables messages cache. Only 'db' cache is supported.
$rcmail_config['messages_cache'] = false;


// ----------------------------------
// SMTP
// ----------------------------------

$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = '';


$rcmail_config['smtp_port'] = 25;


$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = '';


$rcmail_config['smtp_pass'] = '';

$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN';

// Optional SMTP authentication identifier to be used as authorization proxy
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_cid'] = null;

// Optional SMTP authentication password to be used for smtp_auth_cid
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_pw'] = null;


$rcmail_config['smtp_helo_host'] = '';


$rcmail_config['smtp_timeout'] = 0;
```

These are the entries in sendmail.log:

```
[26-Dec-2013 08:45:52 +0100]: User sender@gmail.com [::1]; Message for receiver@gmail.com; 
[26-Dec-2013 08:57:22 +0100]: User sender@gmail.com [::1]; Message for receiver@yahoo.com;
```

There are no entries for today in error.log

Can anyone please help me out here and tell me what could be going wrong ?

Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: You should enable logging in the RC config.

Comment: Yes logging is enabled, I have updated the question with the logged entries..

Answer (score 3):

xampp on windows 8. That smells like a home setup instead of a proper server, domain and mail config. This will fail horribly for email as many providers will block mail sent from home DSL connections due to spam issues. So don't do this. If you really want your own mailserver, get an el cheapo VPS with a proper mail setup on it.

Comment: Okay, so do you mean to say that Roundcube is working fine ?
I actually want to build an application with Roundcube on my xamppp server and then upload it to a proper server!

Comment: Which is all very well, but if you bother to read the basic document on posting to SF, http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic, you'll see in big bold letters that questions about **anything in a home or development environment** are explicitly off-topic.